# How to add launch parameter to Google Chrome on Linux?

Tags: linux, google-chrome

I wanna run Chrome on Linux with the parameter `--enable-speech-input`.

Can anyone tell me the steps to do this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the command:

```
google-chrome --enable-speech-input
```